# enlarge input search component in npx create-react-app using antd input component

Tags: reactjs, search, input, components, antd

I am using antd Input Search Component. [This is the link which I followed](https://ant.design/components/input/)  I have used size="large" in Search component, but I want to increase its size a little more, and increase its width as well. Is there a command to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/t4bei?file=/index.js) given in the documentation, you can play with the css and see that you can do the following:

```
.ant-input-affix-wrapper-lg,  
.ant-input-affix-wrapper-lg input {
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

`.ant-input-affix-wrapper-lg` will expand the wrapper and the icon inside, but not the text inside the input. for this you also need to add the second line `.ant-input-affix-wrapper-lg input` to target the input.

Note that the icon isn't part of the input, therefore you need to increase the font-size of **both**. Just play with it and do as you wish :)

Since you want to increase the size of a specific input, I recommand not putting the code in the css like that. You should add a wrapper to your component or around your input to target this one specifically, something like :

```
#search-component .ant-input-affix-wrapper-lg,  
#search-component .ant-input-affix-wrapper-lg input {
  font-size: 70px;
}
```